# Why does this pointer appear to point to itself?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get to grips with pointers in C and am struggling to understand why I am getting a strange output.

My code is:

```
int main(){
```

```
int a[3][6];
int i,j,k = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        a[i][j] = k++;
    }
}

int c = 5;
int *p = &c;
printf("address of p = %p\n",&p);
printf("p = %p\n",p);
printf("address of c = %p\n",&c);

printf("address of a[2] = %p\n", &a[2]);
printf("address of a[2][0] = %p\n", &a[2][0]);
printf("a[2] = %p\n", a[2]);
printf("a[2][0] = %d\n",a[2][0]);

return 0;
```

}

And the output I get is:

```
address of p = 0x7fff6cbabf88
p = 0x7fff6cbabf90
address of c = 0x7fff6cbabf90
address of a[2] = 0x7fff6cbabf70
address of a[2][0] = 0x7fff6cbabf70
a[2] = 0x7fff6cbabf70
a[2][0] = 12
```

This appears to show that `a[2] == &a[2]` but surely this cannot be correct?

Comment: `a[2]` has type `int[6]`; `&a[2]` has type `int (*)[6]`. If you have a pointer to a person and a pointer to a train; put the person inside the train ... do both pointers point to the same thing????

Comment: mind == blown! so confused

Comment: if you ask the pointers above to point to the next thing, they will point in completely different directions (next person vs next train). What I mean is, pointers are identified by both the address and the type they point to.

Comment: I think my problem is that I am trying pointer arithmetic with an array name which isn't a pointer.

Comment: That's not the problem. C has no problem implicitly converting the name of an array to a pointer.

Comment: @lurker: `a[n]` and `&a[n]` are not synonymous! The first is an array (check `sizeof a[n]`), the second is a pointer (check `sizeof &a[n]`). Arrays sometimes are converted to a pointer to their first element. **When that conversion occurs** `a[n]` is synonymous to `&a[n][0]`.

Comment: @pmg thanks, and sorry I was sloppy in my explsnation. I'm aware of the differences. My point was about the addresses.

Answer (score 4):

Start with something simpler, like this

```
int main( void )
{
    int b[5];

    printf( "b      = %p\n", b      );
    printf( "&b     = %p\n", &b     );

    printf( "b+1    = %p\n", b+1    );
    printf( "(&b)+1 = %p\n", (&b)+1 );
}
```

The compiler treats `b` as a `pointer to an int`, whereas `&b` is a `pointer to an array of 5 ints`. Therefore, adding 1 to `b` changes the address by 4 (assuming 32-bit int), whereas adding 1 to `&b` changes the address by 20 decimal.

---

Once you understand that, then you can knock yourself out with the `a[3][6]` array.

```
a        is a pointer to     int [6]
a[i]     is a pointer to     int
a[i][j]  is an int

&a       is a pointer to     int [3][6]
&a[i]    is a pointer to     int [6]
&a[i][j] is a pointer to     int
```

Comment: This puts things into English and makes pointers easier to understand for me. I keep getting confused as I was under the impression arrays are pretty much just pointers and a[5] is converted to a+5 when compiled. However the compiler sees `a as:int (*)[6]` which is what has been confusing me.

Comment: Yep, the `pointers to arrays` syntax in C is mind bending stuff.  You are correct that a[5] is always converted to a+5.  The thing to remember is that pointer arithmetic always involves the size of the object being pointed to, so you need to know what that size is, before doing the math.

Answer (score 1):

The array name is equivalent to a pointer to the first item of the array:  `arr == &arr[0]`.
Your `a` is a two-dimensional array, so `a[0]` or `a[2]` are single-dimensional arrays,
consequently  `a[2] == &a[2][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the identifier of an array, in most cases it decays to a pointer to the first element.

So having

```
int a[3][6];
```

- `&a` is a `int (*)[3][6]`, so `sizeof(*&a)` will be `18 * sizeof(int)`.
- `a` and `&a[0]` both are a `int (*)[6]`, so `sizeof(*a)` and `sizeof(*&a[0])` will be `6 * sizeof(int)`.
- `a[0]` and &a[0][0] both are a `int *`, so `sizeof(*a[0])` and `sizeof(*&a[0][0])` will be `6 * sizeof(int)`.

(Note that all occurrences of `*&` in the `sizeof` expressions can be optimized away; I leave them here for better understanding.)

But all mentioned pointers point to the same location.

Always be aware that a pointer consists of address and type (length), which both are relevant.